# javascript new does not create new object

Tags: javascript, class, oop, object

I am trying to get two objects from the same class definition. However they seem to share the same attribute. What can i do?

http://jsfiddle.net/dagod/nuam8dks/2/

```
myclass = function() {
    this.data.push(Math.random(1000));
};

myclass.prototype.data = [];

a = new myclass();   
b = new myclass();
console.log(a.data);
console.log(b.data); //same as a.data
```

Comment: `data` is shared, since you put it in the prototype. Declare `data` as an own property inside the constructor. Also, use `var` to declare your variables, and capitalize your constructors as a convention, so you don't forget `new`.

Comment: @elclanrs how would i decalre it as own property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just been doing this for something else!

```
myclass = function() {
    this.data = [];

};
```

Now you can access it my simply doing myclass.data =

Personally this is how i'd do it:

```
var MyNameSpace = {
  SomeFunction: function() { 
    Some code
  };
  this.somevariable = somevalue;
};
```

Then you can go myNameSpace.myfunction() or myNameSpace.myVar = Value

Comment: This answer is fairly confusing. Why are you using a namespace? Why have you changed `data` to `somevariable`? Why haven't you written `Some code` out fully? And what's the point of the `|| {}` at the end?

Comment: I'm using a namespace because if he carries on the way he's going he's going to need to have his code accessible from numerous places in his application, so it makes sense to have it there. The question wasn't anything to do with data specifically it was to do with variable scoping, as for the || {} I appear to have overshot my cut and paste or got it mixed up

Comment: Even large projects don't always benefit from namespacing within a file. Anyway, OP's code is likely to be boiled-down version of a much longer script (so we can concentrate on what's important), which may already contain namespacing. I realise explaining general principles is at least as important as fixing this bug, but I still say renaming `data` was confusing. It's unnecessary to point out that the same principle applies regardless of the property's name. It's sometimes good to point out problems OP may have missed, but you must clarify that it's a digression, not part of the answer.

Comment: Yep I accept that, perhaps it was due to the fact that i'd had exactly the same problem recently given that I just moved from C# to JS so I had the advantage of reading between the lines. I'll revise my answer shortly to better reflect the thought process behind the answer.

Comment: And for the record from my perspective there aren't really any excuses for not namespacing something like this, from a programming perspective why would I want to use "window." since its not part of the window "class" then it has no place joining that namespace.

Comment: I didn't mean they should use global variables. Global variables are a terrible idea. I just meant that they didn't need `MyNameSpace`, and `myclass` should be a declared variable.

Answer (score 0):

See the comment from elclanrs.

```
var Myclass = function() {
    this.data = [];
    this.data.push(Math.random(1000));
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare your member variable inside the constructor instead of making them part of the prototype. oop in javascript can be ugly and unintuitive. (Thats why there are so many oop libraries out there for javascript)

[Using ds.oop](https://github.com/digital-synapse/ds.oop/wiki)

```
ds.make.class({
    type: 'MyClass',
    constructor: function(x){
        this.a = x;
    }
});

var c1 = new MyClass(1);
var c2 = new MyClass(2);

console.log( c1.a ); // output: 1
console.log( c2.a ); // output: 2
```

Answer (score -1):

You can get the desired results as follows:

```
myclass = function() {
    this.data = Math.random(1000);
};

//myclass.prototype.data = [];

var a = new myclass();   
var b = new myclass();
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mLcg27e6/1/)

Comment: Uhhh, `Math.random()` doesn't take an argument and doesn't return an array.  I don't know how this could possibly do what the OP asked for.  You're just putting a random number into `this.data`.  The OP wants a unique array for each instance that is seeded with a unique value.

Comment: You are correct about random not taking a parameter, but please read the question carefully. He does not ask for an array, he merely asks why two instances of the same class are returning the same random number value. Doesn't this answer satisfy that question? See the jsfiddle.